# Matlab debug: skip next line without execution

Tags: matlab, debugging, undocumented-behavior

**Questions:**
(full description of problem is below)

- Does anyone have a suggestion on how to trick Matlab into skipping a line or several lines of code? (mex / java / rewriting some internal Matlab features?)
- Does anyone know where `db*` code files may be located (if exist)?

There are several functions in Matlab that allow flow-control while debugging / running a program: `dbstop`, `dbcont`, `dbstep`, etc... I was trying to find a `db*` function that would skip the next line in a Matlab script, `dbskip` perhaps, but sadly there is no such builtin functionality and it doesn't seem like this [feature](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/119349) going to be ever implemented (10 years and counting).

**EDIT** example of use:

The following script, `myScript`, may call a function `myFunc` which decides on whether to skip the next line in the caller script based on the value of its input, like so:

```
% myScript.m 
x = 1;
myFunc(x);
x = 2;
x = 3;

% myFunc.m
function myFunc(u)
   if u == 1
       % skip next line in caller -- how to?
       % ... do more stuff ...
   else
       % ... do other stuff ...
       disp('Business as usual.')
   end
   % ... do even more stuff ...
end
```

**EDIT**

One way of achieving this, as @Michael Smith suggested, is to write a program that would read `myScript.m` and execute it line by line skipping any line that is specified at runtime. I believe that this solution is a good start; however, in more complex cases, there would be function calls within function calls. So, making a truly general solution using this approach, would require writing a full blown Matlab code interpreter having all the capabilities that Matlab has plus some of my own requirements. This is something I would like to avoid if I can use some of Matlab's inherent reflective capabilities or by hacking into the debugging system.

In the meanwhile, I hit another wall trying to find how and where `dbstep` is implemented. When debugging any of the`db*` functions the result is the following error:

```
Error using <db*> 
Debug commands only allowed when stopped in debug mode.
```

The only `dbstep.m` file I could find, contains documentation without any code so I assume that it is a compiled built-in.

Comment: You can comment out particular line/s that you want to skip!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama, true; however, you cannot comment-out lines while the program is running. `db*` functions work while the program is running.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with built-in function at this moment, even with the latest version (2016a).

Comment: @AlexanderF. how does one achieve something like that in other languages/environments...? I _guess_ you _could_ use `global` variables for that... Think of it like some "general debug flag".. Or wrap relevant code in a call to `shouldExecuteThis()` function which has a persistent `executionMode` setting (possibly a combination of binary flags) that you can change during runtime if you so desire... If this makes sense to you, I can write an answer that illustrates this approach.

Comment: @Dev-iL. I suppose in other languages I would use some variation of `goto <label>`. Could you see a way for your approach to produce a fully general solution with complex call hierarchy, where the decision to skip a line (or more) could be made anywhere along the way, and without crippling the code with too many `shouldExecuteThis()`?

Comment: Well, the hierarchy depth isn't an issue... The problem is with the `goto` philosophy itself - it's considered a very bad practice. Perhaps I don't understand what your problem is and why you chose the solution you asked about, but my feeling is that you're on the wrong path here. Perhaps you could explain the use case in more detail? It's possible that once your problem is clear somebody could suggest an easier solution. Right now it seems that `if shouldExecuteThis(), <code>; end` is a fitting solution.

Comment: @Dev-iL. `goto` is a fine tool if it fits the job. I've used it in Fortran before and it just needs some getting used to. In my case it's even easier since I only skip forward.

Comment: @Dev-iL. I think the engineering _problem_ that I am trying to solve is well defined in the question, but I will give some background. In a nutshell, I'm writing my own language, `myLanguage` that I would like to be seamlessly integrated into any Matlab script, function or class. I would like Matlab to be able to ignore a block of `myLanguage` when it reaches some predefined set of keywords, since it wouldn't make much sense to it anyway. I could very well write an interpreter or use `if shouldExec()...` but, for aesthetic reasons (vain, I know), I would like it to work as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this might get a little messy.  I can think of two possible ways to do this.  One of them involves editing your script to have every line have an if statement looking at a local variable that you can modify in the workspace.  I'm going to just call this one out.  So lets look at the next idea.

matlab has a command eval(EXPRESSION) that takes in a string and executes.  Here's the thought.  Lets create a script/function for debugging with something like the following:

```
FID = fopen('<filename here>');
no_skip = true;
line_no = 1;

executing_script = 1;
while(executing_script == 1)
    line_no              %Print the line number
    line = fgetl(FID)    %removed the ; so it will write the line
    if(no_skip)
       eval(line)
    end
    line_no = line_no + 1;
end
```

Having a breakpoint in there will allow you to modify the value of no_skip while you're on the breakpoint, making the script not execute the next line.

Let me know if this helps.

Upon further looking it appears you're going to have to make sure your while loops are closed...  so this might be a little more complicated if you're using if/while in the script...  Sorry.

Comment: You can have it print the line in there too, so you know where you are.  Or even call out the line number.

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at it. I think that taking care of the corner cases shouldn't be a problem because there is a finite number of `for`, `while`, etc... I thought of doing something similar myself, but wanted a more organic way of running a program without having a dedicated script to interpret it. That's why I'm seeking a hack to the debugging system. It may not have been clear in the example I gave in my question, but once `myFunc` skips a line in the caller workspace, it doesn't necessarily return, it may have more statements to execute based on the line it skipped/read.